# Documenting Python params that are duck-typed

Tags: python, documentation, pydoc

I have a function `foobar` which expects its parameter `baz` to be any object that implements `__gt__` and `__eq__`.

```
def foobar(baz, qux):
    """
    :type baz: Any object that implements __gt__ and __eq__
    """
    if baz >= qux:
        return 'nice!'
    return 'ouch!'
```

Are there any conventions on how you should document these types of parameters? I'm using Python 3.5 if it matters.

Comment: You can add try-except block to process situations when you can't compare parameters objects and add description to documentation.

Comment: Also check [Comparable types with mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965083/comparable-types-with-mypy).

Comment: `object` has the attributes `__eq__` and `__gt__`, so wouldn't your criterion be true as long as you go down the mro deep enough?

Comment: @timgeb: Didn't think of that to be honest, good point. The question is really about documenting this type of duck-typing, so let's pretend that's not the case? :)

Comment: Did you make some progress?

Comment: @timgeb: Afraid not, I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but I'm not sure how it relates to the question about documenting the parameter type?

Comment: @damd maybe you missed the type hint at the end of the code. You can now do `def foo(arg: FooAndBar): ...`. Type checkers should be able to inform you when you are passing an argument without the methods you require.

Comment: By the way, the answer is a little hardcody which is OK when assuming there are only a few relevant methods. If you wanted to abstract further, you could write yourself a function that accepts a list of method names and dynamically creates an ABC with said methods and the corresponding subclasshook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little pointless for `__gt__` and `__eq__` because `object` has those attributes.

> @timgeb: Didn't think of that to be honest, good point. The question is really about documenting this type of duck-typing, so let's pretend that's not the case? :)

In the general case, I suppose you can write yourself an ABC that implements `__subclasshook__` and then typehint that class.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class FooAndBar(metaclass=ABCMeta):
     @abstractmethod
     def foo(self):
         raise NotImplementedError

     @abstractmethod
     def bar(self):
         raise NotImplementedError

     @classmethod
     def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
         if cls is FooAndBar:
             has_foo = any('foo' in X.__dict__ for X in C.__mro__)
             has_bar = any('bar' in X.__dict__ for X in C.__mro__)
             if has_foo and has_bar:
                 return True
         return NotImplemented

class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        pass

class FooBar:
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

print(isinstance(Foo(), FooAndBar)) # False
print(issubclass(Foo, FooAndBar)) # False
print(isinstance(FooBar(), FooAndBar)) # True
print(issubclass(FooBar, FooAndBar)) # True

def func(arg: FooAndBar):
    pass
```

Note that defining `foo` and `bar` in `FooAndBar` is not needed for your specific purpose (the subclasshook triggers anyway) but omitting the methods would look very weird to me, and probably any reader of the code.